# Should `wwroot/bin/AspNet.Loader.dll` be ignored by source control?

Tags: asp.net, dll, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying out Asp.Net vNext and when I was going to add my stuff to source control (git) I discovered there is a `bin` folder in my `wwwroot` containing one dll, `AspNet.Loader.dll`.

Is this something that should be checked in, or should the whole `wwwroot/bin` folder be ignored, or?

Comment: ignored by source control. included on publishing.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove AspNet.Loader.dll it will be recreated on next build, so you can safely ignore it in your VSC. Same will happen with other libraries, so ignoring the whole wwwroot/bin folder is even better approach.